# Filtering array by list of keys in PHP 5.5

Tags: php, array

I have an associative array with data (let's say language codes and descriptions) and a second array with allowed keys (lang codes). I want to filter the data array by these allowed keys.

The problem is I'm bound to PHP 5.5 and I can't use [`ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) flag.

I came up with the following solution:

```
$langs = [
 'en' => "English",
 'de' => "German",
 'fr' => "French",
 'ru' => "Russian",
];

$allowed_langs = ['en','de'];

var_export( 
array_map( function($lang) use($langs) {return $langs[$lang];} , array_combine($allowed_langs, $allowed_langs))
);

/* Output as expected:
array (
  'en' => 'English',
  'de' => 'German',
)
*/
```

I wonder is there a more elegant and shorter solution to this task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I always believe that you should use built in functions wherever possible, as opposed to recreating PHP functionality with loops etc. The main reasons for saying this are that:

1. We should trust that PHP functions achieve their desired result in an efficient manner, and:
2. If they are improved in future versions your code doesn't need to change, but just gets better.

That being said, why not something like [this](https://eval.in/612455):

```
$matches = array_intersect_key($langs, array_flip($allowed_langs));
var_export($matches);
```

Comment: Yes, indeed! This solution is definitely better than mine.

Comment: A similar solution is in the PHP [array_filter documentation comments](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#87912), that uses `array_diff_key` instead of `array_intersect_key`

Answer (score 3):

I find your solution rather complicated, so I would prefer this one:

```
foreach ($langs as $k => $v) {
  if (in_array($k, $allowed_langs)) {
    $result[$k] = $v;
  }
}
var_export($result);
```

I' m incertain of which one is faster (and I tend to think this shouldn't be really important here), but I'm sure it's more simple and readable.

Comment: Small comment: - "AS" -> "as" (highlighter doesn't highlight the CAPS).

Comment: @RuslanBes Not sure what you address about highlighter: is it the SO's one? Anyway, I'm not initially partisan for this capitalization: I only resigned using it because it seems to be somewhat part of shared best practices, like for `TRUE`, `FALSE`, and `NULL`... and probably some other ones I don't have in mind at this time.

Comment: @cFreed PSR actually recommends not using caps for true, false, null or as - http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

Comment: @cFreed it's just my perfectionism. If you write `as` then the SO highlighter will make it blue like `foreach` and `if`. Now it thinks apparently that it's a constant. Upvoted it anyway

Comment: @cFreed as C Ivemy said, it's actually the opposite in terms of "best practice"

Comment: @CIvemy Interesting link: I didn't know the PSR initiative. In the other hand I retrieved that "my" current best practice came from drupal.org: and their PAReview is pretty pernickety, so I should now have variable reflexes depending where I'm writing code! Sigh :)

Comment: @RuslanBes Please look at my comment to CIverny. And thanks for your upvote.